# Php Preg_replace String with Array?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I am having some issues with PHP preg_replace.

I have a url that contains a image-url with numbers added, e.g.:

> $url = http://example.com/111.jpg,121,122,123,124,125,126

The numbers at the end are always different.

To seperate the sting, I am using

> $parts = explode(",", $url);

To figure out how many numbers there are, I am using:

> $numbers = count($parts);

**My problem is to replace the end of $url[0] with $parts (starting with parts[1] up to parts[$numbers-1])**

**Any idea what I need to change??**

Here is my code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
   $array[] = preg_replace('/\d+.jpg/',sprintf("%01d.jpg",$i),$url[0]);
}

<img src="<?php echo($array[0]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[1]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[2]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[3]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[4]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[5]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[6]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[7]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[8]); ?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo($array[9]); ?>"/>
```

Comment: Your question is hard to parse. What is your desired output?

Comment: Looks good. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$array[] = preg_replace('/\d+.jpg/', "{$url[$i]}.jpg"), $url[0]);
```

This'll pull out the trailing numbers one at a time. Your original version was replacing with your loop counter, which almost surely were NOT going to be the same as the trailing numbers.

Yours is generating

```
http://example.com/001.jpg
http://example.com/002.jpg
etc...
```

and you want

```
http://example.com/121.jpg
http://example.com/122.jpg
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url   = 'http://example.com/111.jpg,121,122,123,124,125,126';
$parts = explode(',', $url);
$url   = array_shift($parts);

$parts_count = count($parts);
for($i=0; $i<$parts_count; $i++) {
  $array[] = preg_replace('/\d+.jpg/', sprintf("%d.jpg", $parts[$i]), $url);
}

var_dump($array);
```

outputs

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/121.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/122.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/123.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/124.jpg"
  [4]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/125.jpg"
  [5]=>
  string(26) "http://example.com/126.jpg"
}
```